# Strange behavior (maybe just me) from the python file handling code

Tags: python, fopen

I just started learning file handling in python3. The code I try to create accepts user provided file name, opens the file, then print out the total number of lines and characters within the file.

The question is that I have to declare different variables (fh and fl in the following example) for the line and character count separately.

In the following working-as-expected code, if I comment out `fl = open(fname)` line and change `for line in fl:` to `for line in fh`, then the line count in the output becomes zero (not expected).

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
fh = open(fname)
text = fh.read()
fl = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fl:
  count = count + 1
print("line count in", fname, ":", count)
print("word count in", fname, ":", len(text))
```

Does that mean in the future if I were to process string functions on the same file, I have to declare different variable and read the same file multiple times? Is there a way to achieve "read once, use many times" goal?

Comment: why are you opening two files `fh` and `f1`?

Comment: Read the contents and save it to a variable: `lines = fl.readlines()`

Comment: Because since you already read the file, the handler fh points to the end of file, use fh.seek(0) to reset fh position

Comment: "Strange behaviour... from the python string code" - perhaps this title could be improved. The issue is not with any "string code" but rather with how the file objects are used.

Comment: @O.O. Changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you read lines from the file you opened, the offset you are at currently is also kept track of. So after you have read all the lines (as in the for-loop), the position will be at the end of the file.

You can use `f.seek(0)` to set the current position in the file back to the beginning. Then you can do the `for line in f` again and go through the same contents twice, without having to `open` it twice.

See [file methods](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Of course you could also both store the contents and count the number of rows in a single loop as you read through the file; or use the `readlines` method to get a list of the rows in the file. Using the readlines method would be a good way to read the files only once and get the contents in a useful format.